# 'push' of undefined in my constructor in Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

Still learning Angular. Seeing this when trying to fill an array of numbers inside a constructor

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

trying to fill an array in my constructor like this

```js
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
  user: User;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  bsConfig: Partial <BsDatepickerConfig> ;
  emailErrorMessage: string;
  userErrorMessage: string;
  currentYear: number = new Date().getFullYear();
  startYear = this.currentYear - 120;
  years: number[];


  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router,
    private alertify: AlertifyService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    for (let i = this.currentYear; i > this.startYear; i--) {
      this.years.push(i);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize the properties of your class.

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
 years: number[] = [];
 ...
```

Comment: My bad! I assumed the first set of brackets was the init. Thanks!